# php sessions appear in other directories

Tags: php, session, directory

I have some folders in my server where i have several scripts which use sessions for several actions.

For example my admin panel on folder1 has a session called adm_sess which tells me if i am logged in or not.

Then when i go to folder2 which has nothing to do with the previous script, and i do

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

i see that session(adm_sess) and that causes my server sessions to interact with other sessions created in other folders and change them dynamically.

Why does that happens and how can i make the sessions on each folder be active only within that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [session_name();](http://www.php.net/session_name)

before

```
session_start();
```

call

```
session_name("first");
session_start();
```

and for second

```
session_name("second");
session_start();
```

Comment: instead of session_start() ? isnt session_start required for sessions to work?maybe add session_name('name') before session_start?